# Early proofs of Leibniz's formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, math-history

Wikipedia attributes [Leibniz's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) to  Madhava of Sangamagrama, James Gregory and Gottfried Leibniz. But what were their proofs?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_of_Sangamagrama http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/various/piGregory.htm                             http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/various/piGregory.htm

Comment: sorry about the format

Comment: @ Alex - I don't see a proof in the article on Madhava of Sangamagrama. Thanks for the other reference. I wish we had a reference that tied Gregory's proof down to a specific historical source.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_of_Sangamagrama#The_value_of_.CF.80_.28pi.29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good reference for this question is Ranjan Roy: *The Discovery of the Series Formula for $\pi$ by Leibniz, Gregory and Nilakantha*. Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 63, No. 5, December 1990, pp. 291-306. The article is reprinted in Berggren et al.: [*Pi: A Source Book*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441919155).

Gregory did not publish his results on series, but he corresponded with John Collins in London from 1669 until his (Gregory's) death in 1675, and the arctan-formula is contained there. The correspondance was published by Turnbull in 1939.

In the title of his article, Ray has chosen to name Nilakantha rather than Madhava who lived a century earlier. The reason is that we do not have the original text of Madhava; while he is credited by Nilakantha, it is not clear if this also includes the arctan-formula.

Comment: The article is available online [here](http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/carl-b-allendoerfer-awards/the-discovery-of-the-series-formula-for-pi).